# EF Core SplitToTable complex object

Tags: entity-framework-core, ef-code-first

I want to create table `OrderPrices` for entity `Order`.

```
public class Money
{
    public decimal Amount { get; }
    public string Currency { get; }
}

modelBuilder.Entity<Order>(
    builder =>
```

I can do like this, but I get the error :

> The 'Money' property 'Order.Amount' could not be mapped because the database provider does not support this type. Consider converting the property value to a type supported by the database using a value converter.

```
        builder
            .ToTable("Orders")
            .SplitToTable(
                "OrderPrices",
                tableBuilder =>
                {
                    tableBuilder.Property(o=> o.Price);
                    tableBuilder.Property(o=> o.Discount);
                }
```

I should do this, but I can't because EF Core doesn't have such extensions

```
        builder
            .ToTable("Orders")
            .SplitToTable(
                "OrderPrices",
                tableBuilder =>
                {
                    tableBuilder.OwnsOne(b => b.Price, builder =>
                    {
                        builder.Property(b => b.Amount).IsRequired();
                        builder.Property(b => b.Currency).HasMaxLength(3).IsRequired();
                    });
                    tableBuilder.OwnsOne(b => b.Discount, builder =>
                    {
                        builder.Property(b => b.Amount).IsRequired();
                        builder.Property(b => b.Currency).HasMaxLength(3).IsRequired();
                    });
                }
```